# Select remaining records from two tables (tableB - tableA)

Tags: mysql

How to select records that exists in tableB but not in tableA (basically it is like tableB - tableA)?

I have following tables: (each table have 1 million records)

```
tableA
    id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    name varchar(50)
    sku varchar(10) index
    description text

tableB
    id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    stock int(11)
    price int(11)
    sku varchar(10) index
```

Note: sku is indexed.

1. tableA and tableB have one to one relation in sku field.
2. Both table have 1m records
3. I want to get records that exists in tableB but not in tableA (basically it is like tableB - tableA). LEFT JOIN and NOT IN sucks (very much slow).

What can be alternative solution?

Following are the query I tried:

```
LEFT JOIN query:
    SELECT a.sku FROM tableA a
    LEFT JOIN tableB b
       ON a.sku = b.sku 
    WHERE a.sku is NULL

NOT IN query:
    SELECT * from tableB where sku NOT IN (SELECT sku from tableA)
```

Comment: HI Strawberry, I added full table definition (edited question)

Comment: The id is primary key, both are VARCHAR (10) sorry for my typo, let me edit my question

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is either the `left join` or:

```
select *
from tableB b
where not exists (select 1 from tableA where a.sku = b.sku);
```

The problem with the `not in` solution is that a `NULL` value in `tableA` will result in no rows being returned in the query.

For performance, you need an index on `tableA(sku)`:

```
create index tableA_sku on tableA(sku);
```

This will speed both the `left join` and `not exists` versions.

Comment: Gorden, it slow same as NOT IN

Comment: What do you consider as "slow"?  It does have to check a million records.

Comment: It takes 1 hour. More than 3 minute, I would consider as slow

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar . . . That is highly unreasonable, especially with an index.

Comment: Okay, what can be the options so it does not takes hour. Let us say 5 minutes or so. There should be some solution as many big data analysis is done in MySQL, 1million is nothing for Big data, as they work billion (or more records)

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar . . . You should edit this question (or ask another) that includes the tables and their sizes and the explain plans for the queries.  I am still guessing that the index doesn't really exist for some reason and MySQL is using nested loop methods.

Answer (score 0):

Preparing the environment to replicate the issue:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insertMe` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertMe()
BEGIN
 DECLARE i BIGINT DEFAULT 2;
  WHILE (i <= 1000000) DO
   INSERT INTO tableA(id,NAME,sku,description) VALUES(i,CONCAT('name',i),CONCAT('sku',i),CONCAT('description',i));  
   IF(i%2=0) THEN
       INSERT INTO tableB(id,stock,price,sku) VALUES(i,i%10,i%5,CONCAT('sku',i)); 
       END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
 END WHILE;
/*
CALL insertMe();
*/
END $$

DELIMITER ;

CREATE INDEX idx_tableA ON tableA(sku);
CREATE INDEX idx_tableB ON tableB(sku);
```

Query(using left join) for your requirements has been executed in 1-2Sec in My test environment(2 Virtual CPUs with 1G RAM).

Your left join query and query mentioned by @Gordon Linoff don't have any issue, I'd suggest to verify the index usage by execution as suggested by GordonL.

Next, I am suspecting for stale table statistics in the MYSQL database for the performance issue. Please try following script then see the performance of your query.

```
ANALYZE TABLE tableA;
ANALYZE TABLE tableB;
```

Last but not least, try backup/recreate both tables and their indexes along with above analyze statements, then see the performance of query. It fixes the issue of row chaining and migration.